# Add image to a link button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid_Organisationtable" runat="server"  CssClass="string"
             SelectedIndex="0" DataKeyNames="OrganisationID"
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowDeleting="Grid_Organisationtable_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="Grid_Organisationtable_RowEditing"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="95px" Width="492px">     
<Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit Controls" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" CommandName="Edit" runat="server"
                                ID="btn_Edit" ToolTip="Edit Organisation" />
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrganisationID") %>' CommandName="Delete" runat="server">delete</asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am having a link button in the grid view to delete a row from the grid, I want to add a image to the link button instead of the text delete. how can I add image to the link button. I dont want to use image button. Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Place an  tag in between the

```
<asp:LinkButton>
```

and

```
</asp:LinkButton>
```

tags, just like you would a normal hyperlink.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrganisationID") %>' CommandName="Delete" runat="server"><img src="pathtoimage.jpg" alt="delete group" />delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: how to put the ToolTip="Delete Org"

Comment: The tool tip is controlled by the "alt" property of the image.  Set alt="Delete Org".

Comment: NO, tooltip is int the "title" attribute :P

Answer (score 14):

Will this not work?:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrganisationID") %>' CommandName="Delete" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/someimage.jpg" style="border-width: 0px;" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: That works, just as my answer does.  I tried them both out in a web app just now to be sure.  +1 for a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't use text property of link button and did this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtag" runat="server" CausesValidation="false">
  <asp:Image ID="imgdelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/delete.jpg" />
  <%# Container.DataItem %>
</asp:LinkButton>
```