# Add image to LinkButton programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to insert an image to a LinkButton programmatically like the following aspx code:

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ><img src="NewImages/tick.jpg" runat= "server" /></asp:Linkbutton>
```

I am trying the following code:

```
 LinkButton bb = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)pagerTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0];
    bb.Attributes.Add("img", "NewImages/tick.jpg");
```

P.S PLease do not tell me to use an ImageButton :). There is a reason using this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add image to a link button in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445254/add-image-to-a-link-button-in-asp-net)

Comment: Why don't you want to use an `ImageButton`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something along the lines of

```
bb.Controls.Add(new Image { ImageUrl = "NewImages/tick.jpg" });
```

i.e. create an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx) control and add it to the `LinkButton`'s child controls.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" />

LinkButton1.Text = "<img src='NewImages/tick.jpg'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
LinkButton bb = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)pagerTable.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0];
               HtmlImage i =  bb.Controls[0] as HtmlImage;
            i.Src = "~/NewImages/tick.jpg";
```